# Is there any tip to solve equations involving the exponential and logarithms?

Tags: calculus, logarithms, exponential-function, problem-solving

How to solve this equation :
$$\left ( \exp \left ( x \right )-1 \right )\left ( \ln \left ( \exp \left ( x \right )-1 \right ) \right )-x\exp \left ( x \right )\ln \left ( x \right )=0$$

Comment: I would begin by using exp(0)=1, ln is inverse of exp, exp(a+b)=exp(a)exp(b)

Comment: ln(xy)=ln(x)+ln(y) seems handy too.

Comment: this equation can only be solved by a numerical method,e.g. Newton-Raphson method

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, this is a transcendental equation which will not show analytical expression for the roots (except the trivial $x=0$) and only numerical methods, such as Newton, will be required.

So consider $$f(x)=\left(e^x-1\right) \log \left(e^x-1\right)-e^x x \log (x)$$ $$f'(x)=e^x \left(\log \left(e^x-1\right)-(x+1) \log (x)\right)$$ and use the iterative scheme $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$

Looking at the plot of the function reveals that the root is close to $2.5$. But, let me be very lazy using $x_0=3$. The successive iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 3 \\
 1 & 2.658444549 \\
 2 & 2.462103808 \\
 3 & 2.398181899 \\
 4 & 2.392043125 \\
 5 & 2.391990039 \\
 6 & 2.391990035 
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for ten significant figures.